# AspectJ: intercepting methods based on parameter values

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am using AspectJ to intercept a method called `Request(String, String)`. For that I am using my own specified (marker) annotation. This is what the class looks like:

```java
Class myclass {
    public void Request(@Intercept String t, String u) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The aspect that intercepts the `@Intercept` annotations:

```java
@Aspect
class someAspect {
    @Intercept
    @Around("execution(public * * (@Interceptor (*), ..))")
    public void capture(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, my aspect is intercepting based on the annotated parameters. But I want the aspect to intercept the method request on specific values which the parameter t contains.

For example, if `t == "t1"`, the method must be intercepted, otherwise not.

I was wondering if it is possible to do this in AspectJ (in combination with Spring AOP).

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are a few issues with your code (I just reformatted it so it is at least readable):

- In Java class names are usually in camel case, i.e. `MyClass` or `SomeAspect` instead of `myclass` or `someAspect`.
- Method names in Java begin with lower case characters, i.e. `request` rather than `Request`.
- You are mentioning two annotations `@Intercept` and `@Interceptor`. From now on I will assume that actually we are dealing with just one called `@Intercept`, okay?
- You also annotate your aspect's advice with `@Intercept`, but I guess this is not intended, is it? It might lead to infinite recursion in another pointcut if the intercepting advice is intercepting itself...

As for your actual question, then answer is: sort of, but not statically within a pointcut (because parameters are only determined during runime) but dynamically, also during runtime. You have two options:

**Option A: `if`-`else` within advice code**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Intercept {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void one(@Intercept String string) {}
    public static void two(String string, String string2) {}
    public static void three(@Intercept String string, int i, int j) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        one("foo");
        two("foo", "bar");
        three("foo", 11, 22);

        one("bingo");
        two("bingo", "bongo");
        three("bingo", 33, 44);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class InterceptorAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(@de.scrum_master.app.Intercept (*), ..)) && args(text, ..)")
    public static void normalPointcut(String text) {}

    @Around("normalPointcut(text)")
    public Object capture(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, String text) {
        if (text != "bingo")
            return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs())
            System.out.println("  " + arg);
        // Do something before calling the original method
        Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        // Do something after calling the original method
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Option B: use `if()` pointcut**

The [`if()` pointcut](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697) is a static method returning a boolean value based on the dynamic condition you want to test. The refactored aspect would look like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class InterceptorAspect {
    @Pointcut("if() && execution(public * *(@de.scrum_master.app.Intercept (*), ..)) && args(text, ..)")
    public static boolean conditionalPointcut(String text) {
        return text != "bingo";
    }

    @Around("conditionalPointcut(text)")
    public Object capture(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, String text) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs())
            System.out.println("  " + arg);
        // Do something before calling the original method
        Object result = thisJoinPoint.proceed();
        // Do something after calling the original method
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the dynamic, parameter-based condition has moved into the pointcut which is no longer a `void` method with an empty body but a `boolean` method returning the result of the parameter check. Furthermore, the pointcut expressen got prepended by an `if() &&` expression.

**Console log:**

The console output for both aspect variants is exactly the same:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.one(String))
  foo
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.three(String, int, int))
  foo
  11
  22
```